# How to custom label colour which under the xAxis?

Tags: ios, charts, swift3, ios-charts

Recently,I am using "Charts" frameworks in my App.
Does any one know how to change  label colour which under the xAxis ?

[image: Just like pic. showed]

please help me, thanks

Comment: Check this :  http://www.chartjs.org/docs/

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the "Charts" framework from: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts ?

If so, this should work:

```
XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();  
xAxis.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

More customization of the X-Axis can be found here:
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/XAxis

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help . After inserted "self.lineChartView.legend.textColor = UIColor.white" the legend part could become the colour I want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! , But implement in iOS platform.
But I use following code.

```
    self.lineChartView.xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.white
    self.lineChartView.leftAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.white
    self.lineChartView.rightAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.white
```

it turns out that xAxis and yAxis become white colour but label still stay in black...

[it is wired...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZ5ul.png)

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you say "label still stay in black",but it's not axis's label.It's legend.

You should change it by use

```
chart.legend.textColor = yourColor
```

Default is black.
Good luck~